# Solving a particular differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation:

$$y''-\frac{3}{2(1+x)(2-x)}y'+\frac{3}{4(1+x)(2-x)}y-\frac{Kf(x)(1+x)^2y}{2x(1+x)(2-x)}=0$$

Here $K>0$ is a fixed constant and $f(x)$ is some (as yet) unknown function of $x$, which is in our hands to chose.

What I want is that I should decide $f(x)$ suitably to find a solution $y(x)$ of the above with the condition $y(0)=1$ where $y(x)$ is a rational function of $x$, i.e. a quotient of two polynomials. The solution should not be free of $K$.

I tried setting $f(x)$ so that the coefficient of $K$ becomes $1$ but the differential equation turned out to be so complicated that I could not solve it.

Can anyone offer any help or suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R(x)$ be any rational function such that $R(0)=1$ and define
$$
f(x)=\Bigl(R''-\frac{3}{2(1+x)(2-x)}R'+\frac{3R}{4(1+x)(2-x)}\Bigr)\frac{2x(1+x)(2-x)}{(1+x)^2R}.
$$
The $R$ is a solution of your equation with $K=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I am not looking for a solution which is free of $K$, or is true for a fixed value of $K$.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question.

Comment: Quite simply, I want a solution which is a rational function of $x$ but the term $K$ is present in that solution (eg $(1+Kx)/(1-x)$.)